# OpenVPN internal IP calls

Tags: openssl

I'd like to setup a OpenVPN Server, connect multiple devices and have a software (database included) that can communicate with the devices that are connected on to the server. The software will be located in the same network.

Q1: How is the software going to communicate (send & receive data) with the VPN network IP addresses? If I give my OVPN devices IPs in the 10.0.0.0/8 subnet, will the software be able to communicate with all connected devices? My concern is that it will look for external IP addresses instead of the internals.

Q2: Will I be able to SSH for example, from OVPN Client A to OVPN Client B? (I will be enabling INTERNALNETWORK in my setup configuration)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How is the software going to communicate (send & receive data) with
>   the VPN network IP addresses?

Using whatever RFC1919 address you assign to your OpenVPN private network.

> If I give my OVPN devices IPs in the 10.0.0.0/8 subnet, will the
>   software be able to communicate with all connected devices? My concern
>   is that it will look for external IP addresses instead of the
>   internals.

You'll use RFC1918 addresses for all of your communication. The applications on either side of the connection have *absolutely zero* knowledge that this traffic is traversing an OpenVPN tunnel.

> Will I be able to SSH for example, from OVPN Client A to OVPN Client
>   B?

Sure, presuming you configure your firewall rules accordingly.

Comment: About the answer on my last question, which firewall rules are you referring to?

Comment: The ones the govern what traffic can flow between your OpenVPN devices.